# How to read file from ZIP archive to memory without extracting it to file first, by using C# .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, zip, archive

.NET Framework 4.5 added support for ZIP files via classes in `System.IO.Compression`.

Let's say I have .ZIP archive that has `sample.xml` file in the root. I want to read this file directly from archive to memory stream and then deserialize it to a custom .NET object. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adapted from the [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875(v=vs.110).aspx) manual pages.

The `ZipArchiveEntry` class has an `Open()` method, which returns a stream to the file.

```
string zipPath = @"c:\example\start.zip";

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    var sample = archive.GetEntry("sample.xml");
    if (sample != null)
    {
        using (var zipEntryStream = sample.Open())
        {               
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleClass));  

            SampleClass deserialized = 
                (SampleClass)serializer.Deserialize(zipEntryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, [as documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to add a reference to the .NET assembly `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` in order to use the `ZipFile` class.